# NoMethodError in Roasts#index - undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was just updating two column names in two models, (`Countries` & `Regions`) and now when looking at pages for another model `Roasts`, I'm suddenly getting a NoMethodError.  I can't work out what I've done.  I just rolled back the two migrations, and as I suspected, this hasn't resolved the issue. There is a relation in that `Roasts` `has_many :countries`, and `Countries` `has_many :regions`. I have a nested form to add countries and regions on the roasts#new form.

Just can't spot what I've messed up.

**roasts_controller.rb**

```
class RoastsController < ApplicationController
has_many :countries      
accepts_nested_attributes_for :countries

  def index
      @q = Roast.ransack(params[:q])
      @roastsalpha = @q.result.order(:name)
      @roastcount = Roast.count(:country)
      @roasts = Roast.all
  end
```

**roasts/index.html.erb**

```
<% @roasts.each do |roast| %>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-block">
    <div class="media">
      <div class="media-body">
        <%= link_to roast_path(roast) do %> <h3 class="mt-0"><%= roast.name %></h3><% end %>
        by <%= roast.roaster %><br />
        <hr />
        <i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i> - <%= roast.bestfor %><br />
        <i class="fa fa-tint" aria-hidden="true"></i> - <%= roast.roast %><br />
        <i class="fa fa-sticky-note-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> - <%= roast.tastingnotes %><br />
        <hr />
        <p><small>Added on - <%= roast.created_at.strftime("%e %B %Y") %></small></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br />

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines need to go in your `Roast` model, not in your controller:

```
has_many :countries
accepts_nested_attributes_for :countries
```